# Como salvar informações numa matriz?

Tags: java, array, matriz

Mestres do Java, estou aprendendo sobre matrizes, vetores e gostaria de saber o que acontece meu código, pois crio uma matriz para receber seis nomes e seis cargos para a matriz funcionários. Só que ao imprimir, só imprimi os cargos e não está imprimindo os nomes. Segue abaixo o código:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {

    //Criando o Array vetor do tipo String com seis posições
        String funcionarios[][] = new String[6][1];
        //Populando o array vetor                
        for(int nome = 0; nome <= 5; nome++)
        {
            String entrada = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Digite o Nome do Funcionário: ");
            for(int cargo = 0; cargo <= 0; cargo++)
            {
            entrada = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Digite o Cargo do Funcionário: ");

                funcionarios[nome][cargo] = entrada;                
            }                
        }
        for(int nome = 0; nome <= 5; nome++)
        //Imprimindo o conteúdo do array vetor
        {
            //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nome do Funcionario " + funcionarios[nome][cargo]); 
            for(int cargo = 0; cargo <= 0; cargo++)
            {

               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cargo do Funcionario " + funcionarios[nome][cargo]); 

            }
        } 
    //Encerrando o sistema
    System.exit(0);
```

Quem puder me ajudar, eu agradeço de antemão.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 //Criando o Array vetor do tipo String com seis posições
 String funcionarios[][] = new String[5][1];
```

Você nesse momento deveria criar uma matriz com 5 linhas e duas colunas (nome e cargo) e não uma matriz com 6 linhas e 1 coluna.

Exemplificando a sua matriz com 1 coluna pode ser vista assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sendo que para salvar o nome e o cargo deve ser assim (2 colunas): 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
 //Populando o array vetor                
 for (int nome = 0; nome <= 5; nome++) {
  String entrada = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Digite o Nome do Funcionário: ");
  for (int cargo = 0; cargo <= 0; cargo++) {
   entrada = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Digite o Cargo do Funcionário: ");

   funcionarios[nome][cargo] = entrada;
  }
 }
```

No trecho acima, eu não recomendo o uso de variáveis do tipo inteiro com os nomes que você utilizou como: `cargo` e `nome`, pois fica confuso!

```
for (int nome = 0; nome <= 5; nome++) {
```

Você também não precisa deixar fixo o tamanho da matriz no laço, pode utilizar a propriedade: `length` (que retorna o tamanho).

```
for (int cargo = 0; cargo <= 0; cargo++) {
```

O laço do cargo também é inútil pois ele roda apenas uma vez você pode utilizar a posição diretamente.

Não está salvando o nome pois você não salvou ele.

Você recebe a entrada:

```
String entrada = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Digite o Nome do Funcionário: ");
```

Mas depois sobrescreve ela dentro do for:

```
entrada = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Digite o Cargo do Funcionário: ");
```

E salva o cargo na posição 0:

```
funcionarios[nome][cargo] = entrada;
```

Segue abaixo como seu código vai ficar com essa correções:

```
String funcionarios[][] = new String[5][2];

for (int i = 0; i < funcionarios.length; i++) {

    String nome = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Digite o Nome do Funcionário: ");
    funcionarios[i][0] = nome; // salvando o nome na posição 0

    String cargo = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Digite o Cargo do Funcionário: ");
    funcionarios[i][1] = cargo; // salvando o cargo na posição 1
}

// Mostrando os valores
for (int i = 0; i < funcionarios.length; i++) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nome do Funcionario " + funcionarios[i][0]);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cargo do Funcionario " + funcionarios[i][1]);
}
```

Comment: Gostaria de agradecer muito, pela didática da explicação, me ajudou bastante, muito grato mesmo pela ajuda.

Comment: Disponha amigo! Se a resposta conseguiu te ajudar, aceite ela como resposta basta clicar no visto abaixo das setas de votação.